# Custom property in annotation for bean validation

Tags: java, spring, annotations, bean-validation

```
public class DateTimeValidator implements ConstraintValidator<DateTimeValidate, DateTime> {

private static final OffsetDateTime START_TIME = OffsetDateTime.parse("2015-10-20");

@Override
public boolean isValid(DateTime value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
    if (value == null) {
        return true;
    }

    if (value.getStartTime().isBefore(START_TIME)) {
        String msg = "this is invalid";
        setConstraintViolationMessage(START_DATE, msg, context);
        return false;
    }
}

@Override
public void initialize(DateTimeValidate constraintAnnotation) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
```

Is there a way I can make START_TIME dynamic? Here in the example I have hardcoded the value in the class itself. Is it possible that I can externalize this property in a properties file and when the validator is compiled it picks up the property from properties file for START_TIME.

Comment: I don't see you why you wouldn't be able to read anything in the resouce folder. Did it give you any error?

Comment: That works. But this way I would be making a static variable. If I have to change this value for a different use case, I would have to duplicate this entire implementation with a new property in props file to read the value from that new property. Any better way?

Comment: I don't know your system, but if you use beanvalidation 1.1 and f.e. CDI you can inject the START_TIME.